# Нужна ли запятая в предложении перед словом "определено"?

Tags: запятые

Ответственным за осуществление задач, своевременное осуществление их реализации по планам определено Министерство.

Comment: У вас трижды употреблено одно и то же понятие (осуществление, осуществление и реализация) - нужна разгрузка фразеологии. _Ответственным за осуществление задач с соблюдением плановых графиков определено Министерство._

Comment: Лучше написать так: "За своевременную реализацию указанных планов  (плановых графиков) отвечает Министерство". Осуществление задач - это и есть их реализация по планам. А вообще-то это предложение можно отправить составителям пособия «Пиши, сокращай», где изложены основы информативного стиля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, но после «по планам» я бы поставил факультативное тире, так как части составного именного сказуемого «определено» и «ответственным» слишком оторваны друг от друга, и тире внесет удобство в восприятие текста.
Ответственным за осуществление задач, своевременное осуществление их реализации по планам — определено Министерство.